# What's wrong in my tomcat pool setting? MaxIdle it seems that it does not work

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, connection-pooling

The postgresql status on my server shows me an idle number greater than the one configured in my tomcat

```
systemctl status postgresql-9.4.service | grep idle -c
284
```

In other words:

```
select count(state) from pg_stat_activity where state like 'idle' 
284
```

The settings in my context.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context  allowCasualMultipartParsing="true">
    <Resource 
               name="jdbc/postgres" 
               auth="Container"
               type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
               driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
               url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1"
               username="postgres" password="*****" 
               initialSize ="30"
               maxTotal="300" maxIdle="20" maxWaitMillis="30000"
               closeMethod="close"
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout="5"
               removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
               removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
               removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
               logAbandoned="true"
      />

          <Resource 
               name="jdbc/postgresDb2" 
               auth="Container"
               type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
               driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
               url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db2"
               username="postgres" password="*****" 
               initialSize ="30"
               maxTotal="300" maxIdle="20" maxWaitMillis="30000"
               closeMethod="close"
               validationQuery="SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout="5"
               removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
               removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
               removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
               logAbandoned="true"
      />
</Context>
```

The connections in my code are like this:

```
 public String asignacionMax(String type) throws ModuleException, Exception{      
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;  
    String accountno="";
    try{
        String query = "select nextval('public.asignacionseq');";
        conn = getConnection("GU");
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);   
        ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery();    
        String cnt="";
        if(rst.next()){
            cnt = rst.getString("nextval");
            for(int i=cnt.length();i<9;i++){
                cnt= "0"+cnt;
            }   
        }
        accountno = type+cnt;

    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new Exception(e);
    }finally{
        if (conn != null) {conn.close();}
        if (stmt != null) {stmt.close();}
    }
    return accountno;
}
```

Info about my system:

Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.5
Server built:   Feb 6 2018 21:42:23 UTC
Server number:  9.0.5.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_161-b14

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made some changes after reading the suggested topics.

Answer (score 0):

[Tomcat jdbc pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) defines `minEvictableIdleTimeMillis` attribute to control how long a connection must be idle to be considered evictable.

> minEvictableIdleTimeMillis
>
> (int) The minimum amount of time an object may sit idle in the pool before it is eligible for eviction. The default value is 60000 (60 seconds).

Your configuration does not specify this attribute so it's 60 seconds by default.

> 1) Idle connections should be counted over that period to check it's variation.
>   2) Two pools are defined so it could be expected to have twice the number of idle connections at some point.
>   3) Evictable connections are checked every 5 seconds by default so you could check every 3 seconds during 61 seconds with:

```
timeout 61 watch -n3 "systemctl status postgresql-9.4.service | grep idle -c | tee idle.log"
```

`idle.log` should contain the values found over that period.
Another aspect of the issue is to make sure that your verification method is appropriate from pool perspective, in other words if `idle` means the same for both.

Comment: I was testing your suggestion and the number never decreases but increases. About the meaning, my opinion is that idle is the same since we are talking about database in both cases.

Comment: Now I added an "-a" to the code to check better if it decreases or not ... and I see that it usually decreases by 1 and then increases again.
But the numbers are always rising everytime I check.

Comment: About two hours later the number has dropped to 50% of the last time. But it continues to increase and the number of the one configured in the tomcat remains different.

Comment: Regarding your code, I think stmt is closed before conn. Anyway, it could be a connection leak.

Comment: Maybe it could be about that. But my question is to clarify whether the number configured in the tomcat pool does not correspond to what happens in my database. And why the numbers continue to increase ignoring that configuration.

Comment: btw, what's the code inside `getConnection("GU")`? Are you referencing the pool there?

Comment: There is no reference to the pool. It is just a way to indicate the database that will be used.

Comment: In other words, how are you getting the connection? Are you sure it comes from the pool?

Comment: I am getting the connection through the context.xml which is where the pool configuration is saved.

Comment: Do you have something like this in your code? `Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/postgresDb2");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();`

Comment: Yes I have it.. and I'm sure that my connection comes from the pool.. that's the reason of my question

Comment: Have you counted ESTABLISHED connections on command line for that port? Should match the other number.

Comment: Yes, it's almost the same .. plus the active connections that I have... what can I guess about that to help me with my problem of the pool settings that are ignored ..

Comment: perhaps on db server side to get a count of queries by connection ID if possible. May be there's such activity that connections are not idle more than 1 minute thus never evicted. Also, please add record examples of `systemctl status postgresql-9.4.service` output, may be there's something interesting there.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is nothing in that command more than the idle that I mentioned. I would like to focus on the problem of the tomcat side since there is the configuration of the pool that is being ignored. Thank you for your comments.